# Compare files in Java?

Tags: java, file, compare

How to compare any types of two files in Java?

I'm able to compare 2 text files, but I need to compare any type of files (like xls,doc,jpp...etc.)

I just need a Boolean result (for any type of files) telling if the files are the same or not.

Comment: You can do it. Goahead.

Comment: How are you comparing the text files? You can simply compare every file type bytewise, not that hard...

Comment: How about using `md5sum`? Will that work for you?

Comment: DIdn't check md5sum.Checked text files only

Comment: why "too broad" ? It is simple, non ambiguous, clear. No reason to close it IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first compare the files length, then you can compare files content byte by byte and return false as soon as a difference is found.

```
public static boolean sameContent (File f1, File f2) throws IOException {
    if(f1.length()!=f2.length())return false;
    FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(f1);
    FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(f2);
    try {
        int byte1;
        while((byte1 = fis1.read())!=-1) {
            int byte2 = fis2.read();
            if(byte1!=byte2)return false;
        }
    } finally {
        fis1.close();
        fis2.close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

One note about md5 comparaison (suggested in comments) :

- Comparing md5 of the files is not reliable because md5 of 2 different files can be the same (if you are unlucky).
- Computing md5 requires reading the whole file (+ hashing algorithm) and so is less efficient

Comment: Perfectly its working.Thanks..